# Halloween: How can werewolf work in US?

Tags: society, law, shapeshifters

Among those scary monsters visiting us every year, some must have been accustomed to us after several visits. If they wish to stay in US after the Halloween and work as foreigner from the Otherworld, **what work laws need to be made/changed to accommodate these guests?**

> **Note:** I'm asking because my acquaintance asked about his prospect on working there after the next Halloween. As a **werewolf,** he needs a good job to feed his pack of 5. His friends may ask to come, too, if the government willing to accommodate them and protect their rights as a law-abiding citizen. *Don't worry about the human,* they are accustomed to meat steak and bacon. In fact that's why they want to stay there!
>
> Their main concern are safety, discrimination, and their nocturnal tendency.

**Update:** Answers ideally should include what law that may prevent them from staying and working for 1 year. They do not have to cite the exact wording of the law, but it will be nice to do so.

Some already mentioned immigration law. That will be great if you can include what is needed for the werewolves to become **a legal worker in US.** What **occupation** is *not* needed, but still it will be nice if you provide that.

I'm thinking about law about **protected class.** Would it be required to include "race" as protected class? Let's assume that the government will try their best to accommodate these guests, but without breaking the law (by altering them or make exception). The law should also be able to accommodate **future visitors** from the Otherworld.

Comment: Why does Halloween matter? I thought werewolves were mostly concerned with the 3 days of the full moon?

Comment: American werewolves should stay in London.

Comment: @CaM they are only planning on 1 year stay. And they are permanent werewolf (they are not originated from human, after all)

Comment: @Alexander or Paris

Comment: "Should" is a poor word for questions on this site. Questions need to be specific and answerable.

Comment: what makes them werewolfs instead of anthro wolfs?

Comment: @Vylix Synonyms of should are just as problematic. Can you provide clear criteria so that we can assess how well the question is answered?

Comment: Werewolves share some traits in common with wolves: good night sight, superior smell sense, pack instinct.

A good job where these skills come handy is border guard on night shift. And with the current attitude of the US government versus immigration, it's likely that such skills will be rewarded with a green card.

Comment: Immigration laws would still apply. Can the werewolf qualify for a temporary work permit, H1B visa or other form of documentation? IS he planning to become a legal immigrant (i.e. applying for a green card?) Does he wish to become a US Citizen? Don't forget ICE will look very poorly on an illegal immigrant, regardless of points of origin.

Comment: The basic question is, does the werewolf hold a passport issued by a country recognized by the U.S.A.? Because otherwise he cannot possibly be allowed across the border; countries tend to insist that visitors present travel documents duly issued by a state in amicable relations.

Comment: Being a werewolf, I could "fix" your political system. :-)

Comment: @sphennings the actual question is "what laws" not "should the law changed". I think answers that cite law that might interfere with their visit are good?

Comment: @Thucydides no, it's only a 1 year visit. They want meat steak and bacon, so they must work. I'm not familiar with all the documents needed for this.

Comment: @AlexP Let's assume the Otherworld opened up diplomatic relation just prior to this request, so they are from a "country" recognized by USA.

Comment: @Vylix. Unless the Werewolf has special skills that no American (or American Werewolf) has, and an employer is willing to sponsor him, then US Customs and Immigration will probably not issue a work permit. H1B's, for example, are visas generally issued to IT workers when his companies claim there are not enough trained Americas to do IT work (this is horribly abused BTW). If ICE discovers an illegal werewolf in the US, they will take steps to track him down and remove him. His best bet is ICE probably does not have much experience with supernatural immigrants.

Comment: @Vylix, why don't you check U.S. Department of State for [visa requirements](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/employment/temporary.html)? Exactly the same rules would apply to supernatural creatures if the USA has diplomatic relationships with their country. Of course, there can be some special laws to prevent dragons from coming, but it is outside the scope of your question...

Comment: Where do werewolves come from to visit the US, and why should they do this only on Halloween? Does the US suck in werewolves from the rest of the world just to celebrate Halloween? Maybe its a cultural thing?

Comment: @LeeLeon from the Otherworld! I'm not sure how they get here, but they always wait in my basement between 6-7 PM. I haven't asked them about the werewolves in other countries, but I'll make sure to do so when they visit this Halloween.

Comment: I don't know if there is any laws that would even recognize werewolves as people. Werewolves would probably start out without any human rights. That means people will just enslave them and make them work like farm animals once they figure out that all they'd need to do is set a trap in their basement every Halloween.

Comment: The first ones to show up will likely get shot tho because if anyone or anything on someone's property without invitation, it is legal in most states to shoot first and ask questions later.

Comment: Easy: He lives in New York City. No one will bat an eye... and it's not limited to Jack Nicholson!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think a new or special law is needed for this. Especially if you want to avoid discrimination. During the day they can work any job they like and there might be some new jobs just for them during the night (asuming they are in control when shapeshifted). And if they commit a crime in werewolf form that's on them. Law applies to everyone.

Comment: As this is currently written this is more of a comment than an answer. If you [edit] this you will reduce the chance that this gets deleted for not being an answer.

Comment: It is an answer. The answer is: no new law. The ones that are in place are already good. And why do people on this site hate simple answers? Btw appreciate the feedback and will delete it if you think it has no value.

Comment: The point you are trying to make is a good one. In fact it's the same track I would have gone with if I had answered this question. How you've written it reads more like a comment than an answer. You can [edit] your question to be clearer with what you are saying which is something along the lines of "The laws as they currently exist are good enough"

Comment: I think this does answer the question asked. Welcome to WorldBuilding *blackorange*! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: And a little tip: you can notify users by writing an "@" in front of their name. For example @Secespitus would notify me. It even autocompletes. The writer of a post is always notified and if there is only one person who commented on your post and you write another comment they are also notified. It's only possible to notify one person with each comment.

Comment: Looks like an answer to me! If there's some tragedy, there could be a social movement to have a registry, like what happened for sex offenders, That movement didn't affect which acts were legal.

Comment: Do you think "race" (human/non-human) should not be a protected class?